# Best strategy for windows and web application vs DB

Tags: .net, sql-server

Here is the situation.
I had develop a WinForm application for a client. We’ve used a SQL Server database that was installed on one of the server on the local domain.
So far everything is working fine. 
Now, the client would like to add a web based application for a portion of the application and they want that portion to be accessible from the internet through a tablet device. Both remote user and local user need to see the same data at the same time.
We are now facing a challenge to connect to the local SQL Server.

If the request would have been to only be able to use the application remotely, a simple VPN connection would have done the trick.
But because the remote employees are only using a tablet device, looks like we only have the option to build a restricted public web application.
I’m curious to know what would be the best approach for the data access portion?
I was thinking about the following:

- use SQL Azure and move the local database to a SQL Azure database. That way, Winform and web app can connect to the same database. Not quite sure if the client is willing to accept that his database will be on a remote Microsoft server…!
- Another option would probably be to open the local SQL Server to the Internet and allow remote connection. To me, that’s the last option that I would consider based on security issue.
- Another option may be to have both SQL Server local database and SQL Azure for the web application and have the needed data synchronize between both server

I’m really curious to know what you guys would suggest in that kind of environment. We need to keep the Winform application and we need to be able to access the data through a tablet device.

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't create a web-service's layer exposing the functionality needed?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you develop a ASP.NET web application, host it on a local server and allow this to connect to the SQL database.

You would need to configure your router/firewall to direct http traffic to this server.

You could secure login using Integrated Security if your client can be provided with a domain login, or alternatively use ASP.NET Forms Authentication.

For easy development of a nice looking application that is compatible with tablets/phones etc, I would recommend using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Paul Grimshaw's answer.

However, If you want to create an application specific to the tablet (iOS, Android, etc). You could create a WCF service that has access to the SQL database, hosted on a server at the clients site. Then expose the WCF service to the web and get the required data via the WCF service.

More than likely you could re-use a lot of the current WinForm applications code for the service. In this case, you would create a WinForm and self-host a WCF service that has an HttpBinding.